# Laravel 5.2 debugbur exception

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5, phpdebugbar

I have debugbur exception when i'm trying to get record from DB

```
$news = \App\Models\News::findOrFail(1);
```

After this laravel throw exception

```
ErrorException in LaravelDebugbar.php line 291:
Missing argument 2 for Barryvdh\Debugbar\LaravelDebugbar::Barryvdh\Debugbar\{closure}()
```

my composer.json

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
    "laravelcollective/html": "dev-master",
    "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.1"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "2.8.*|3.0.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "2.8.*|3.0.*"
},
```

Comment: upgrade laravel debugger developer has made changes for 5.2

Answer (score 0):

Looking at last changes in https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar/commits/master it seems it should work now, so run in console:

```
composer update barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
```

to update this package